# Comparing Date types Angular 5 - getDate() not a function

Tags: angular, angular5

Sorry for the very generic wording of the title I couldn't think of a better way to describe what I'm trying to do.

code below are highlights of my home.component.ts

```
completedOrderTotal: Order[] = [];
completedOrderDay: Order[] = [];

 getCompletedOrders() {
    this.loadingCompletedOrders = true;
    var totalCompletedOrders = 0;
    var now = new Date();
    this.orderService.get(6).subscribe((order) => {
        this.completedOrderTotal = order.filter((c) => c.COMPLETED == true);
        this.completedOrderDay = order.filter((d) => d.COMPLETED == true && d.DATE_COMPLETED.getDay() < now.getDay()-1);
        this.totalCompletedDay = this.completedOrderDay.length;
        this.totalCompletedOrderTotal = this.completedOrderTotal .length;
        this.loadingCompletedOrders = false;

    });
}

export class Order {
   BUY_ORDER_ID: number;
   SELL_ORDER_ID: number;
   COMPLETED: boolean;
   BUY_TOTAL: number;
   SELL_TOTAL: number;
   BUY_TRIGGER: string;
   DATE_CREATED: Date;
   DATE_COMPLETED: Date;
}
```

order.service.ts (API Service)

```
 @Injectable()
export class OrderService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   get(id: number) {
       return this.http.get<Order[]>('api/order/' + id);
   };
}
```

I want to have a 2 objects holding 2 sets of data.
1. All Orders that have completed
2. All Orders that have completed in the last 24 hours

i'm struggling with this line:

```
 this.completedOrderDay = order.filter((d) => d.COMPLETED == true && d.DATE_COMPLETED.getDay() < now.getDay()-1);
```

I get the error d.DATE_COMPLETED.getDay() is not a function.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You're getting JSON from your backend using the HttpClient. JSON doesn't have a Date type. It has strings, booleans, numbers, arrays and objects. So an Order can't possibly have a field of type Date.

Also, you should really improve your naming conventions. The method `get()` taking an ID as argument, getting from a URL `api/order/{id}`, and the name `order` all suggest that what is returned is a single order. And yet it seems to be an array of orders.

Finally,

```
order.filter((c) => c.COMPLETED == true);
```

should simply be

```
order.filter(c => c.COMPLETED);
```

Comment: But isn't it mapped to the angular Order class? I've only been doing angular2+ for 2 days so still unsure how typesript works with subscribe/map

Comment: That has nothing to do with subscribe()/map(). All HttpClient is doing to transform your JSON into an object is JSON.parse(body). That won't, ever, create an instance of a class. It will create a POJO that has the same structure and types as the JSON. JavaScript can't possibly guess that you want the field DATE_CREATED of the JSON transformed to a Date (how?), and that the result must be an instance of a class Order that it knows nothing about anyway.